# Python: Reading from list of URLs while passing in params

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Python question here...I have two files that contain the following data:

`hosts.txt`:

```
google.com
target.com
bing.com
```

`strings1.txt`:

```
x
y
z
```

I'm trying to construct URLs and make GET requests to them by reading the list of hosts in `hosts.txt` while passing in the list of strings from `strings1.txt` as query params. However, **My Script** only makes requests to line 1 of the `hosts.txt` and all strings from `strings1.txt`, but then the script terminates(See: **Output**). How can I pass in the list of query params to the first host then move on to the next host in line 2 of `hosts.txt` file using the same query params and so forth? I tried using the `next()` method, but had trouble there. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**My Script**

```
    with open('hosts.txt','r') as file:
        with open('strings1.txt','r') as strings:
            for line in file:
                host = line.strip()
                for string in strings:
                    url = f"https://{host}/?test={string}"
                    resp = requests.get((url)).status_code
                    print(f'Results for {url}\n{test}')
```

**Output**

```
Results for https://google.com/?test=x
 302
Results for https://google.com/?test=y
 302
Results for https://google.com/?test=z
 302
[...SCRIPT TERMINATES...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're exhausting the `string` iterator (which iterates over lines in file `strings1.txt` so you see only the one iteration over hosts). Instead, read the hosts/strings to a list and make requests afterwards:

```py
with open("hosts.txt", "r") as f_hosts:
    hosts = list(map(str.strip, f_hosts))


with open("strings.txt", "r") as f_strings:
    strings = list(map(str.strip, f_strings))

for h in hosts:
    for s in strings:
        url = f"https://{h}/?test={s}"
        print(url)
        # requests.get(url)
        # ...
```

Prints:

```
https://google.com/?test=x
https://google.com/?test=y
https://google.com/?test=z
https://target.com/?test=x
https://target.com/?test=y
https://target.com/?test=z
https://bing.com/?test=x
https://bing.com/?test=y
https://bing.com/?test=z
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is related to how you are reading the strings from strings1.txt within the loop. Once you reach the end of the file, subsequent attempts to read will not produce any more values. To iterate over the lines of strings1.txt for each host, you need to reopen the file or seek back to the beginning.

```
import requests

with open('hosts.txt', 'r') as file:
    with open('strings1.txt', 'r') as strings:
        for line in file:
            host = line.strip()
            
            # Rewind the strings file to the beginning for each host
            strings.seek(0)
            
            for string in strings:
                string = string.strip()
                url = f"https://{host}/?test={string}"
                resp = requests.get(url).status_code
                print(f'Results for {url}\n{resp}')
```